# What is the origin of the parsec?

Tags: astronomy

In astronomy the parsec is a unit of length:

A parsec (abbreviated pc) is a unit of distance used by astronomers, cosmologists, and astrophysicists.

1 parsec is equal to $3.08567758\times10^{16}$ meters, or $3.26163344$ light years

I think this is a rather arbitrary number. Somewhat like a (land)mile being about $1.5\dots$ kilometers.

What is the ratio behind this number?

Comment: If you get definite answers, there is an option to accept them.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question shows the lack of basic research.

Comment: @OON Yeah, you are right about that. Guess I was lazy... Others though will now know too, might they be interested and lazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This word was coined by H. H. Turner.

par- (in parallax n.) + sec- (in second)

> A unit of length equal to the distance at which a star would have a
> heliocentric parallax of one second of arc, approximately equivalent
> to 3·086 × 10^13 kilometres (19·2 × 1012 miles, 3·26 light years).
>
> 1913   F. W. Dyson in Monthly Notices Royal Astron. Soc. 73 342
> There is need for a name for this unit of distance... Professor [H.
> H.] Turner suggests Parsec, which may be taken as an abbreviated form
> of ‘a distance corresponding to a parallax of one second’.

Ref: *Unabridged Oxford English Dictionary*.

BTW, This is an excellent resource for word origins but it is not public. Good libraries have subscription or you can buy your own annually.

Comment: Wouldnt the parmin be more suited for astronomical distances? Cosmic distances?

Comment: @Deschete Schilder  An astronomical parallax is the angle that an object appears to move sideways when viewed from different points in the Earth's orbit.  So the larger the parallax, the smaller the distance; the smaller the parallax, the larger the distance.  If a parmin is a distance where an object would have a parallax of one arc minute, it would be 1/60 as far as a parsec.  At parmin distances the only common objects would be comets , asteroids, and dwarf planets, in the outer solar system, most of them far too too distant & faint to be detected from Earth.

Comment: A "parmin" would be $\frac{1}{60}$'th the distance of a parsec, too little for the nearest stars and too big for planetary distances. *(moments later)* It looks like M.A. Golding and I got to this question and commented at essentially the same time. I was probably a couple of minutes later, despite the 20-30 second posting difference, since my comment took much less time to write.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro - well, sure, but how many seconds of arc were you behind?

Comment: @Jon Custer: Are you alluding to the [Star Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars) howler ["made the Kessel Run in less than 12 parsecs"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22made+the+Kessel+Run+in+less+than+12+parsecs%22)? When I saw the movie (summer 1977, just after I finished high school) I was totally awed by the special effects and attention to detail (although I was a little put off by ["in a galaxy far, far away"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22galaxy+far%2C+far+away%22), **(continued)**

Comment: which suggested to me that the writers didn't know the difference between solar systems and galaxies **[\*]**), and then I nearly groaned out loud when I head the parsec comment, along with my best HS friend that I saw it with, who also immediately recognized the faux pas. **[\*]** If each household/apartment dwelling is a solar system, then just our galaxy alone would correspond to the dwellings on 100-200+ Earths.

Comment: These comments are very entertainable reading!+1 for all.

Comment: @M.A.Golding Now I see why I didnt got notified. You wrote Deschete meaning something a bit different. Deschele (de schele) means the doubly seeing (schilder means painter, together they refer to the Italian painter "il guercino"). Deschete (de schete(n)) means the farts...